# How to format convert simple Mathematica expressions into a Maxima-compatible format?

Tags: output-formatting, interoperability

I am trying to compare really long algebraic results from *Mathematica* with those from *Maxima*.

*Maxima* can parse the simplest types of expressions output by *Mathematica*, such as `2*x+y`.  But I have results that involve terms like `Sqrt[3]` and I'd really like more of a "universal" result, e.g., `3^(1/2)`.  That way I can `eval_string()` in *Maxima* and compare the two results in *Maxima*.  Similarly, can I format `I` as `%I`?

Here is a sample expressions I have:

```
(1/(320979616137216 z0^6 z1^6))(15552 z0^4 (-9674588160 + 
 53747712 z1^2 - 248832 z1^4 - 2973600 z1^6 - 
 1419008 I Sqrt[3] z1^7 + 1631315 z1^8) + 
72 z0^6 (29023764480 - 1572120576 z1^2 - 642297600 z1^4 - 
 1172903760 z1^6 - 764045056 I Sqrt[3] z1^7 + 1159383225 z1^8) + 
64 z0^7 (9674588160 I Sqrt[3] - 618098688 I Sqrt[3] z1^2 - 
 344818944 I Sqrt[3] z1^4 - 859550688 I Sqrt[3] z1^6 + 
 1550843904 z1^7 + 742039375 I Sqrt[3] z1^8) + 
537477120 z1^4 (-279936 + 
 z1^2 (3888 + 
    z1 (1152 I Sqrt[3] + z1 (-945 - 256 I Sqrt[3] z1)))) - 
35 z0^8 (14511882240 + 
 z1^2 (-1021206528 + 
    z1^2 (-724863168 + 
       55 z1^2 (-43363944 - 24670400 I Sqrt[3] z1 + 
          33942181 z1^2)))) + 
53747712 z0^2 z1^2 (-1679616 + 
 z1^2 (15552 + 
    z1^2 (-2106 + 
       z1 (-736 I Sqrt[3] + z1 (665 + 192 I Sqrt[3] z1))))))
```

Comment: At the very least, use `FullSimplify` on your *Mathematica* output.  (I don't know the equivalent in *Maxima*.)  Please post small examples of representative output.

Comment: `17 Sqrt[3] - 5 Sqrt[2] == 17. 3^(1/2) - 5. 2^(1/2)  ` yields `True`.

Comment: Sorry on not being clear... I want to copy and paste Mathematica output so that i can paste it into the Maxima terminal. The problem is these "Sqrt[]" things... I wanted them as 3^(1/2)...

Comment: What if you try running `FullForm` on the *Mathematica* output?  Then all `Sqrt` will be expressed as `Power[_,1/2]`.  Then copy the result into *Maxima*.

Comment: Take a look at [this package](http://www.johnlapeyre.com/mmacompat/) and let us know if it helped!

Comment: @QuantumDot But will Maxima interpret `"Power[2,1/2]"`?  I don't know Maxima but I wouldn't assume so.  The OP just wants an easy way to output Maxima expression syntax from very limited Mathematica syntax.  This should be very easy in theory with functions like `Format` but when I try to implement it, I bump into too many problems, and I feel like giving up on all this `Format` stuff and just doing it manually.  But then I have to write  formatter for almost every operation, including `Times`, `Plus` ... that's hardly quick and easy.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats.html